# Can't deploy to Heroku because the server refused the connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I wanted to deploy my local Rails app (that works perfectly) to Heroku, but get the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/tmp/build_21pkcz898c28o/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'
```

Followed by many lines about `postgres_adapter`.

I'm a bit disappointed because I red that Heroku overwrite *config/database.yml* so why does it talk about running the server on `127.0.0.1` (I'm not looking for remote db)?

Thanks,

**Update**

If this can help, running `heroku config` gives the following:

```
DATABASE_URL:               xxx
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GRAY_URL: xxx (the same xxx as above)
```

Comment: What command are you running that's leading to that error message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Include the following in your application.rb, above the Module Appname

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

And read the [Heroku Labs: user-env-compile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) Article

Comment: The user-env-compile feature was an old beta feature that has been discontinued, so this no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Rails 4.0.4 and none of the above worked for me.

Following the [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#troubleshooting)

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

then

```
git add public/assets
git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"
```

Resolved it partially for me ... I could 'git push heroku master' but then my Bootstrap styling is not applied.

To resolve this final part, I added the recommended 'rails_12factor' gem in my gemfile.

```
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

And all worked fine after that after my git push