# error: failed to push some refs to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I Am Trying To Push But Not Working

My Gem File Looks Like

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.21'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

and after i command

git push heroku master

```js
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 75, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (62/62), done.
Writing objects: 100% (75/75), 27.31 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 75 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properl
y.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app
.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your depende
ncies at all.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/
bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Resolving dependencies.....
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed
 one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem insta
llation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.4.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 3.2.21
remote:        Installing builder 3.0.4
remote:        Installing activemodel 3.2.21
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing journey 1.0.4
remote:        Installing rack 1.4.7
remote:        Installing rack-cache 1.2
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing hike 1.2.3
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing sprockets 2.2.3
remote:        Installing actionpack 3.2.21
remote:        Installing mime-types 1.25.1
remote:        Installing polyglot 0.3.5
remote:        Installing treetop 1.4.15
remote:        Installing mail 2.5.4
remote:        Installing actionmailer 3.2.21
remote:        Installing arel 3.0.3
remote:        Installing tzinfo 0.3.44
remote:        Installing activerecord 3.2.21
remote:        Installing activeresource 3.2.21
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
remote:        Installing execjs 2.5.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing rack-ssl 1.3.4
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing rdoc 3.12.2
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 3.2.21
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 3.2.2
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 3.1.3
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.2
remote:        Installing rails 3.2.21
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.16
remote:        Installing sass-rails 3.2.6
remote:        Installing uglifier 2.7.1
remote:        Bundle complete! 6 Gemfile dependencies, 40 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Post-install message from rdoc:
remote:        Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby r
doc/ri data:
remote:        <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
remote:        = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
remote:        Bundle completed (80.47s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/p
lugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out an
d bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and
 config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http:/
/weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from
 <top (required)> at /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/Rakefile:7)
remote:        DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/p
lugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out an
d bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and
 config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http:/
/weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from
 <top (required)> at /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/Rakefile:7)
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refuse
d
remote:        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
remote:        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_ad
apter.rb:1222:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_ad
apter.rb:1222:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_ad
apter.rb:1222:in `connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_ad
apter.rb:324:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_ad
apter.rb:28:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_ad
apter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
ection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
ection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
ection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
ection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
ection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
ection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
ection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
ection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
ection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
ection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
ection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:310:in `clear_cac
he!'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:103:in `block (2 level
s) in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__3484
198801275101306__prepare__2196888947682683501__callbacks'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_call
back'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepa
re_callbacks'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbac
ks'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `pre
pare!'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `pre
pare!'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <modu
le:Finisher>'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initiali
zers'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing
'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/config/environment.rb
:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require
'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block i
n require'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_de
pendency'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require
'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in in
itialize_tasks'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in
<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in
<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rak
e_task'
remote:        /tmp/build_b38abca32e7ecaaf883fae6625ceb01f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in
<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !     Attempted to access a nonexistent database:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pre-provision-database
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to mysterious-headland-8039.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/mysterious-headland-8039.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mysterious-headland-8
039.git'
```

Please Help Me Anyone How Can I Get Rid Of This.

There Is Coming Failed To Push Some Refs To .... I Searched Many And Resarched More But I Didnt Find Any Solution.

Please Help Me To Get Rid Of This.

Thanks

Comment: Did you create a database on Heroku?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503073/cant-deploy-to-heroku-because-the-server-refused-the-connection

Comment: yes i created database on heroku

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is with Heroku Postgres database you are using.

```
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refuse
d
remote:        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
remote:        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**DO NOT** do this if you have sensitive data - From your application `resources page` on Heroku can you try to remove the `Heroku Postgres` addon and then add it back.

You can write to heroku support if this is happening in production. You can try the above if you are okay with capturing a db snapshot and storing it back when you get your application working.